# parsing does not work json Android

Tags: android, json

parsing does not work json Android
parsing does not work json Android

```
{
"group_name":"МБА-14",
 "days":[
{
 "weekday":1,
"lessons":[
 {
 "subject":"Научно-исследовательский семинар",
 "type":0,
"time_start":"17:10",
 "time_end":"18:30",
"time_number":6,
"parity":1
}
]
}
]
}
```

I need to get the value weekday. This is my code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(str);
            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonObject.getJSONObject("weekday");
            Log.e("aaaa", jsonObject1.toString() );
```

Comment: What output do you get? Or is it crashing?

Comment: Not, I receive

"group_name" : "МБА-14" , 
 "days" :[ 
 { 
"weekday" : 1 , 
"lessons" :[ 
 { 
"subject" : "Научно-исследовательский семинар " , 
"тип" : 0 , 
"time_start" : "17:10" , 
"time_end" : "18:30" , 
"time_number" : 6 ,

Comment: "weekday" is a string in your json.
So use `String weekDay =jsonObject.getString("weekday");`

Comment: @Kunu. 
I also did. Not Working.

JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(str);
                Log.e("aaaa", jsonObject.getString("weekday") );

Comment: Please post your exact json first.

Comment: In your code What is "str"...

Comment: This is code, working.

JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(str); JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("days"); Log.e("asdas",jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("weekday").toString() );

Comment: Tons of tutorials exist already on the subject. Your question doesn't introduce any problem that needs solving. (-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONArray days = jsonObject.getJSONArray("days");
JSONObject oneDay = days.getJSONObject(0);
int weekday = oneDay.getInt("weekday");
```

Comment: Can you write in Java ?. I Android. 

JSONArray days = jsonObject . getJSONArray ( "days" ); 

jsonObject Cannot resolve symbol 'jsonObject'

Comment: @droonkkisd You forgot the first line: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);`

Comment: @Ircover. And you can get the value like this  "subject". Right Away
 JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(str);
 Log.e("asdas", jsonObject.get("subject").toString());
????????

Comment: By continue of my code, to get lessons in `String` need `oneDay.getString("lessons")`, but it's better to call `getJSONArray` for further work.

Comment: @Ircover. Ok :). Another question . And how do you know the size of the array ?

Comment: For example `days.length()`. I think you [need to read](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) some [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your "str" variable contains this,
then parse like

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(str);
JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("days");
String weekday = (jArray .getJSONObject(0)).getString("weekday");
```